# Set up sendmail in XAMPP in a way that all the mails sent from localhost are sent only to one particular email?

Tags: php, windows, xampp, localhost, sendmail

What I am trying to achieve is if php is sending a mail then it should ignore the $to address and mail them all to one address that we can put in a common place.

I like to test all the mails in localhost, and I have set up php and sendmail settings with my gmail to send all the emails, but the problem is, I might accidentally send a mail to a real person who shouldn't have been receiving that email at that time.

So is there a way I can send/redirect the mail to say "xyz@gmail.com" instead of $to address that i would get through a database without changing the code every time i might want to test a block of code.

I have searched for a solution but couldn't find any.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.